# solr and django-haystack search result nothing,,search_indexes.py?

Tags: django, solr, django-forms, django-views, django-haystack

every one I am trying the solr and django-haystack to make my search,,I can see there are 9 Docs in my solr,,,and in my db there are 9 data actually,,however,,when it comes to search form and search ,,I got no result ,,
I have to search `designer`

> solr

[image]

> models.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image
from django.utils import timezone
.....
class ProductsTbl(models.Model):
    model_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, unique=True,error_messages={'unique':"這 model number 已經被註冊了 ."})
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    material = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    feature = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    release = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    twtime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    hktime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    shtime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    jptime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    suggest = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    cataloggroup = models.ManyToManyField(CatalogGroup)
    place = models.ManyToManyField(Place)
    scale = models.ManyToManyField(Scale)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    useredit = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_imagep_Product, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''

        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()

        return super(ProductsTbl, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

> views.py

```
.....
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
.....
def post_search(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    if 'query' in request.GET:
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            results = SearchQuerySet().models(ProductsTbl).filter(content=cd['query']).load_all()
            # count total results
            total_results = results.count()
        return render(request, 'search.html', {'form': form,
                                                         'cd': cd,
                                                         'results': results,
                                                         'total_results': total_results})



    return render(request, 'search.html', {'form': form,})
```

> settings.py

```
.......
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    .....
    'haystack',
    .....
    )
....
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/designer'
    },
}
```

I guess probably `search_indexes.py` not correct

> search_indexes.py

```
import datetime
from haystack import indexes
from .models import ProductsTbl


class ProductsTblIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    author = indexes.CharField(model_attr='user')
    # created = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='created')

    def get_model(self):
        return ProductsTbl

    # def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    #     """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
    #     return self.get_model().objects.filter(created__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

> search/indexes/designer/productstbl_text.txt

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.user.get_full_name }}
{{ object.body }}
```

> search.html

```
{% block title %}Search{% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
        {% if "query" in request.GET %}
            <h1>Posts containing "{{ cd.query }}"</h1>
            <h3>Found {{ total_results }} result{{ total_results|pluralize }}</h3>
            {% for result in results %}
                {% with post=result.object %}
                    <h4><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h4>
                    {{ post.body|truncatewords:5 }}
                {% endwith %}
            {% empty %}
                <p>There are no results for your query.</p>
            {% endfor %}
            <p><a href="{% url "post_search" %}">Search again</a></p>
        {% else %}
            <h1>Search for posts</h1>
            <form action="." method="get">
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <input type="submit" value="Search">
            </form>
        {% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
```

after I run *python manage.py rebuild_index*

[image]

here is my data in mysql

[image]

there are 9 data ,,just like the solr shows 9 docs,,,
however, after I run the search form ,,,it shows no result

[image]

the solr console just shows

[image]

Comment: Looking at your screenshots, the word "cool" is inside the `name` field of one of your objects. The `name` field is not being indexed anywhere in your `ProductsTblIndex`.

Comment: thank you after I add {{ object.name }} in search/indexes/designer/productstbl_text.txt,,, seems I can get result